# Finding an input sequence given a generating polynomial and CRC

Tags: crc

I am working on a circuit that inputs a 31-bit pseudo-random binary string into a CCITT CRC-16 block which generates a 16-bit CRC output.

I know that M(x)/G(x) = Q(x) + R(x) and the transmitted code will be R(x) appended to M(x). [Q(x) is discarded].

When I simulated the circuit, I got a CRC of 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0. From the help file of the software (VisSim/Comm), I know that the generating polynomial is G(x) = 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1.

**How do I determine the 31-bit input sequence that generated the CRC result?**

Since M(x)/G(x) = Q(x) + R(x), we can say that M(x) = [Q(x) + R(x)]G(x). But we don't know Q(x). Assuming the 16-bit CRC is equal to R(x) and the G(x) is given, how do I go about finding M(x) without knowing Q(x)?

Answer (score 1):

What this is telling you is that there is an infinite number of messages that will produce the same CRC, one for each possible Q(x). All you need to do is pick some particular value of Q(x) and generate the correesponding M(x).

Answer (score 1):

The following is simplistic, but adequate.
Your output space has 2^16 possible values.
Your input space has 2^31 possible values.
On average, for any given output value, there are 2^15 input values that map to that particular output value.  There is no way to tell from a given output value which of those 2^15 possible inputs was responsible, because the mapping from input to output has discarded the information that allows you to reverse the process.

You can't reconstruct the original data from the CRC output, which is fine, that's not the purpose of CRC's.  You can, however, use the combination of the CRC output and the original data to give a pretty reasonable level of confidence (99.7% or thereabouts for a CRC16 and single-bit errors, iirc) that no corruption of the original data or CRC occurred during e.g. transmission over a link with a BER > 0.